# Ensure nginx master process stays running

Tags: nginx, docker, supervisord

I am currently trying to setup a docker container using ubuntu:14.04 as my base image, with nginx and gunicorn/django/celery running inside. I am using supervisor to start all of the processes, and have tested to make sure gunicorn is relaunched when it goes down. However, I can't figure out how to do it with nginx.

My supervisord.conf for nginx is as follows:

```
[program:nginx]
command=nginx
autorestart=false
```

I have autorestart set to false because, from what I can tell, the nginx command simply starts the master process and worker processes, and then exits with status code 0. If I have autorestart set to true, it simply keeps trying to restart that nginx command, which will fail for subsequent retries because the master/worker processes are already running and bound to the port.

On the surface, this seems okay, because if I try and kill a worker process, the master will start another worker to take it's place. But how do I ensure the master process stays running as well?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question but can't you use monit for it?

Comment: Could you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append `daemon off;` to your `nginx.conf` configuration instructing nginx to run in the foreground.

Then modify your supervisor stanza to be:

```
[program:nginx]
command=nginx
autorestart=true
```

It will still spawn master/worker processes/subprocesses and can be used this way in production setups just fine. In this case it's supervisor that runs the process in the background and controls and supervises it.

See this [FAQ entry](http://nginx.org/en/docs/faq/daemon_master_process_off.html)

Comment: Thanks James, this sounds like it would work! Just to make sure I understand what I should see when I make that change though, if I ran ps -ef on the docker, I should see an nginx line, a master process line, and a worker process line, correct? I still don't get that for some reason, even with daemon off; as the first (non-comment) line in my config. I still only get master and worker. And when I kill the master, the master doesn't restart, so only the worker remains up. i even tried adding a "killasgroup=true" option to the supervisor conf. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's a very good question; I'll have to play around with it as I'm not familiar with nginx'x internal process management.

Comment: Sorry, clarification, using your suggested settings, supervisor.log shows:

`2015-06-15 13:37:53,177 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 16`

ps -ef shows:

`root        16     1  0 13:37 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process nginx`

If I `kill -9 16`, the master dies and workers stay running. Supervisor DOES try rerunning `nginx` as per your settings, but keeps complaining:

`bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)`

I think I should force the workers to die with the master, but "killasgroup=true" doesn't seem to be accomplishing that. Any suggestions? Am I missing something?

Comment: You've got ``stopasgroup`` and ``killasgroup`` both set?

Comment: Also don't use ``SIGKILL/9`` as your signal; **NO** process can capture this and do anything about it. use ``SIGTERM/15`` or ``SIGINT/2`` instead!

Comment: Were you using ``SIGKILL/9`` all along and I didn't notice? This *would never* work!

Comment: Thanks James! `SIGTERM/15` and `SIGINT/2` both worked as expected. I was using `SIGKILL/9` and expected it to work because it actually worked on gunicorn (supervisord brought it back), didn't realize it wouldn't work on nginx.

Comment: It doesn't work on nginx because supervisord is not controlling the nginx workers; nginx master is; If you KILL the nginx master there is no way for anything or anyone to recover from that!